# Splash Screen not working on emulator but working fine on android pie or higher, also not working below pie

Tags: java, android

I am creating a splash screen for my android application with a text view only then it runs smoothly everywhere, but if i replace the text view with image then it only works on android pie. Please help. Code is as shown below

```
package com.example.collegeproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView img1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
        Animation myanim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.mytransition);
        img1.startAnimation(myanim);
        final Intent i=new Intent(this,Login_activity.class);
        Thread timer=new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                }catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_screen"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="2000"
    />
```

It shows an error of this application stopped working

Comment: Does't Work means does it crash ? if yes update your question with logcat content

Comment: What error are you having? Add the log to your question if there is any.

Comment: And confirm us when it is working because in the beginning of question you written "if i replace the text view with image then it only works on android pie" and while concluding you written "this works perfectly fine with text view but doesnot work with image view on every phone"